# htaccess internal and external request distinction

Tags: ajax, .htaccess, redirect, external, internal

I have a problem with an `.htaccess` file. I've tried googling but could not find anything  helpful.

I have an AJAX request loading pages into the index.php. The link triggering it is getting prepended by "#" via jquery. So if you click on the link *domain.com/foo/bar* (a wordpress permalink) you get *domain.com/#/foo/bar* in the browser and the content will get loaded via AJAX.

My problem is: Since these are blog posts, external links grab the real link (domain.com/foo/bar), so I want them to get redirected to domain.com/#/foo/bar (cause then ajax checks the hash and does its magic).

Example [here](http://schnellebuntebilder.de).

The jquery code for the prepend is:

```
    $allLinks.each(function() {
        $(this).attr('href', '#' + this.pathname);
...
```

and then the script checks

```
if (hash) { //we know what we want, the url is not the home page!
        hash = hash.substring(1);
        URL = 'http://' + top.location.host + hash;
        var $link = $('a[href="' + URL + '"]'), // find the link of the url
...
```

Now I am trying to get the redirect to work with htaccess. I need to check if the request is external or internal

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^127\.0\.0\.1  #???
```

and if the uri starts with "/#/" which is a problem since it's a comment then, \%23 does not really work somehow.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\%23/(.*)$ #???
```

How do I get this to work to simply redirect an *external* request from domain.com/foo/bar to domain.com/#/foo/bar without affecting the internal AJAX stuff?

Comment: I would suggest a (much easier) client-side solution to your problem. Could you please update your answer with the jQuery code responsible for adding `#` to your links?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your `$allinks` variable is assigned in a fashion similar to this:

```
$allinks = $('a');
```

Do this instead:

```
$allinks = $('a[href^="' + document.location.protocol + '//' + document.location.hostname + '"]');
```

This will transform internal links to your `hash`-y style only.

Comment: Nice thought, but the problem is a little different. I need a solution from external pages e.g. facebook and google that link to a certain blogpost an not the index page. Since the page /foo/bar exists an is indexed the links to these pages point directly to /foo/bar but need to get redirected in the hash-y way so the blogpost is loaded in the right context via AJAX. thx for your help

Answer (score 0):

Ok i've done it with PHP here is the code

```
    $path = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') { 
       echo "It's ajax";
    } else {
     if(strpos($path, '/#/') === false) {
       header("Location: http://schnellebuntebilder.de/#".$path); //ONLY WORKS IF THERE IS NO BODY TAG
     }
    }
```

There sure is a better solution, but this does the trick for now and since the page /foo/bar does, in my case, not include the header.php there is no >body<-tag and the php "header()" function works . If anyone knows the htaccess script for this I am keen to know and learn.